# How to resolve this Rust lifetime issue?

Tags: rust

I am trying to read the contents of files in a directory in parallel. I'm running into lifetime issues.

My code looks like this:

```rust
use std::io::fs;
use std::io;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::comm;
use std::io::File;

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = comm::channel(); // (Sender, Receiver)
 
    let paths = fs::readdir(&Path::new("resources/tests")).unwrap();
 
    for path in paths.iter() {
        let task_tx = tx.clone();
 
        spawn(proc() {
            match File::open(path).read_to_end() {
                Ok(data) => task_tx.send((path.filename_str().unwrap(), data)),
                Err(e) => fail!("Could not read one of the files! Error: {}", e)
            };
        });
    }
 
    let mut results = HashMap::new();
 
    for _ in range(0, paths.len()) {
        let (filename, data) = rx.recv();
 
        results.insert(filename, data);
    }
 
    println!("{}", results);
}
```

The compilation error I'm getting is:

> error: `paths` does not live long enough
>
> note: reference must be valid for the static lifetime...
>
> note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 7:19

I also tried to use `into_iter()` (or `move_iter()` previously) in the loop without much success.

I'm suspecting it has to do with the spawned tasks remaining alive beyond the entire `main()` scope, but I don't know how I can fix this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message might be a bit confusing but what it's telling you is that you are trying to use a reference `path` inside of a task.
Because spawn is using `proc` you can only use data that you can transfer ownership of to that task (`Send` kind).

To solve that you can do this (you could use a move_iter but then you can't access paths after the loop):

```
for path in paths.iter() {
    let task_tx = tx.clone();

    let p = path.clone();
    spawn(proc() {
        match File::open(&p).read_to_end() {
```

The second problem is that you are trying to send `&str` (filename) over a channel. Same as for tasks types used must be of kind `Send`:

```
    match File::open(&p).read_to_end() {
        Ok(data) => task_tx.send((p.filename_str().unwrap().to_string(), data)),
        Err(e) => fail!("Could not read one of the files! Error: {}", e)
    };
```